# How to access the co-ordinates of a shape stored as an object in an array

Tags: processing

I have stored the co-ordinates of several randomly plotted lines in an object array.
I would now like to be able to be able to programatically manipulate for example x1 in all the objects in the array. I cannot work out how to do this or even how to see the co-ordinates of the stored lines. If I do `println()` I just get the memory reference of the objects.

Here is the code so far:

```
class Line{
   public float x1, y1, x2, y2;

   public Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
   }

   public void draw(){
      line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
       float rot = random(360);
      rotate(rot);
   }

   //public boolean intersects(Line other){
   //   //left as exercise for reader
   //}
}

ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

void setup(){
  background(204);
  size(600, 600); 

   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
       float r = random(500);
       float s = random(500);
       lines.add(new Line(r,s,r+10,s+10));


 printArray(lines);
 for(Line line : lines){
      line.draw();

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use dot notation. Using your Line class, you can create a Line object (or instance) using the `new` keyword and the constructor (the special function that has the same name as the class):

```
Line aLine = new Lines(0,100,200,300);
```

Once you have an instance, you can access it's variables(known as properties) using the instance name, then the `.` symbol, then the variable name:

```
println("aLine's x1 is " + aLine.x1);
```

In the example code you have, in the `draw()` function you access the .draw() function(known as method) of the each Line instance:

```
for(Line line : lines){
      line.draw();

   }
 }
```

It's just a matter of using the same concept to access the rest of Line's members:

```
for(Line line : lines){
      //wiggle first point's x coordinate a little (read/write x1 property)
      line.x1 = random(line.x1 - 3,line.x1 + 3);
      line.draw();

   }
 }
```

Be sure to read [Daniel Shiffman's Objects tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/) for more details.